# Using jquery.SerialScroll how do I force a start on a particular page without effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the jquery plugin [SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html). I want it, when initialised, to start on a particular page (ie a list item n numbers in) without the transition effect. And therafter when next or prev is invoked to scroll with the transition effect.

```
$('#screen').serialScroll({
        target:'#sections',
        items:'li', // Selector to the items ( relative to the matched elements, '#sections' in this case )
        prev:'img.prev',// Selector to the 'prev' button (absolute!, meaning it's relative to the document)
        next:'img.next',// Selector to the 'next' button (absolute too)
        axis:'xy',// The default is 'y' scroll on both ways
        navigation:'#navigation li a',
        duration:700,// Length of the animation (if you scroll 2 axes and use queue, then each axis take half this time)
        cycle: false,
        onBefore:function( e, elem, $pane, $items, pos ){
            e.preventDefault();
            if( this.blur )
                this.blur();
                $('.prev').add($('.next')).show();
            if( pos == 0 )
                $('.prev').hide();
            else if( pos == $items.length-1 )
                $('.next').hide();
        },
        onAfter:function( elem ){
        }
    });
```

I suppose I could put it another way how do I suspend /resume the duration variable while I run

```
$('#sections').trigger('goto',[page_index]);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> start: first element of the series (zero-based index, 0 by default).

So I assume can simply use `start:4` to start at the fifth item

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The start element uses the duration variable and will slide to the correct page. I want to start on a particular page with no slide and then have effects thereafter when the user fires a prev or next.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that the start would exactly do what you had intended

Comment: Slow reply I know. Although I couldn't get the start function to work smoothly and ended up implementing a workaround topek was correct in that it is the start's intended purpose. So for that reason I am awarding the correct answer.